# VBA Runtime error '-2147221164 (80040154)': class not Registered

Tags: vba, vb.net, vb6, visual-studio-2019

I developed a class library in Visual Studio 2019 using the .NET framework. Before building the project, I registered the.dll file to interop COM, and this process gave me a .tlb file. This class library was developed in VB.NET, besides that, it has a simple code: one class with one function (class `calcular`, function `Soma`):

[image]

It was possible to include the .tlb file in the reference of VBA and I develop a code in this language that uses the class of VB.NET to build the action of the button:

[image]

On the other hand, when I execute the code in VBA Excel it shows this message:

[image]

If a press the button debug "Depurar" VBA mark the line of the instance of the class

[image]

I read other questions about this error but there isn't a way to solve it without change my machine?

- [ADODB.Connection in VB6 - Open Method fails with Runtime Error '2147221164 (80040154)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570140/adodb-connection-in-vb6-open-method-fails-with-runtime-error-2147221164-8004)
- [VBA Selenium "class not registered"- 80040154](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62239548/vba-selenium-class-not-registered-80040154)

I already made a repair in my MS Office getting to uninstall to install again, can you help me to solve this error that prevents a run of my library in Excel VBA?

Comment: Did you make sure the bitness of your library matches the bitness of your Office installation?

Comment: Don't do all the registration and TLB generation stuff by hand... Visual Studio can do all of that for you

Answer (score 1):

.NET COM visible dlls should be registered using regasm utility with /codebase option.

[Assembly Registration Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/regasm-exe-assembly-registration-tool)

Comment: It works! I Tank you Very Much, Smith. Is important to remember that the (.dll) file needs a simple path and the command used: RegAsm.exe C:\path\file.dll.

Comment: Glad I could help Leonardo.

Answer (score -1):

You must register the DLL before it can be used. Every time you compile a new version you need to run:

```
regsvr32.exe "fullPathAndFileName.dll"
```

You can add a post-build event to the Release in Visual Studio so that it registers the DLL every time you make a new release. If you are distributing this for others then you will need an installer that puts the DLL in to a proper location and then registers it.

You can unregister it by adding the `/u` flag

[Microsoft Topic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-use-the-regsvr32-tool-and-troubleshoot-regsvr32-error-messages-a98d960a-7392-e6fe-d90a-3f4e0cb543e5)